# How can I clean up the information design of these piano notes?

Tags: usability, gui-design, layout, information-design

hopefully i can attach a screenshot here...  I am buried under the complexity of displaying piano notes.
(hmm, thanks editor guy for including the screenshot in the message.  but it's not quite hires enough so link is http://pianocheetah.com/etc/pianocheetah.png )

See how the white notes of the piano are wide at the top (as they are on piano).  I need them to have tails the *same* width as black notes.  because, musically, they're the same "width".  So see how all the white notes look like "dig dug" (not sure if you're old enough to have played that video game).  They lean left or right depending on the hand that plays em.  And they're positioned as they are on the piano keyboard.  But it kinda makes them look strange and freaky looking.  Anybody got a little artistic pizazz that can help me make these things look better?  Somethin curvy maybe?  examples or ideas welcome.

Here is the [link to the screenshot http://pianocheetah.com/etc/pianocheetah.png](http://pianocheetah.com/etc/pianocheetah.png)

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Remove all borders and rounded corners and keep each cell a single solid color.

The best UI is no UI at all so make sure that everything you add absolutely has a reason for being there.  Even simple things like borders and gradients can cause friction to the end user.

[image]

I'm not sure the keyboard is even required to be there.  Perhaps consider having a way to toggle between keyboard mode and note editing modes?

[image]

Comment: I'll give that a quick try.  But note "heads" are important to see - when you hit a note is more important than how long it's held.  There are a lot of cases where the same note is played repetitively.  Also, this doesn't get around the white "dig dug" shaped notes.  They need to look as they do on the piano when hit, and thinner (as they sound) later.  Let me give it a try

Comment: I actually like how the black notes are gray lines and the white notes are white lines.  I would keep that as is and just use solid colors on the already straight bars to indicate note length.

Comment: I would use the key on the keyboard itself as the "note head" maybe by having it fade to the color of the approaching note.  I think it would be less distracting the cleaner you can make the lines (on the keyboard itself as well)

Comment: I'm hoping to have a first attempt, umm, prob tomorrow.  Fighting an important bug today that is, rrr, not bein nice to me.

Comment: Hmmm, well here's what they look like with just no borders.  I think it's an improvement alright.  http://pianocheetah.com/etc/pianocheetah2.png 
    
I might try putting some 45degree angles connecting notehead to tail...

Comment: Welp, thanks Dave.  I guess you have NO competition so you win by default.  Seems weird that nobody is interested in GUIs.  I thought that's what UX was all about.  Ok, whine mode OFF :)  Thanks for your idea.  It's definitely cleaner so far.  I'll look into better transitioning of the white "head" into the tail.